# How to optimize memory usage by python script

Tags: python, memory-leaks

In my docker environment, I have a python script that contains a large number of objects in a dict.
To optimize memory usage, I periodically delete unused objects from dict.
However, I noticed that the RAM is only cleared when it reaches the maximum limit of docker,
whereas I would like it to be cleared immediately upon object deletion.
Can someone help me in resolving this issue ?

Simplified example:

```py
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import gc

big_data = {i: datetime.now() for i in range(1000)}
memory_usage = sys.getsizeof(big_data)
print(f"{memory_usage=} by {len(big_data)=}")
# memory_usage=36960 of len(big_data)=1000

# Delete data
for idx in list(big_data):
    del big_data[idx]

# Trying to trigger garbage collection
# In output you can see empty dict that still using memory. I expect minimal memory_usage.
gc.collect()
memory_usage = sys.getsizeof(big_data)
print(f"{memory_usage=} by {len(big_data)=}")
# memory_usage=36960 of len(big_data)=0
```

Comment: Try to check if your variables in `big_data` are referenced in some other places, if it is the collector won't free space even if the values aren't in the dict anymore. In the loop before the deletion of each key try to `print(sys.getrefcount(big_data[idx]))` this should always print 2 (the reference in the dict and the reference given to the `getrefcount` method itself)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting items from a dictionary doesn't delete the pointer to the memory. Only when the entire dictionary is deleted does it clear the memory.

As a solution you could make a shallow copy of the smaller dictionary and then delete the dictionary that is still holding pointers to the memory like so:

```py
new_big_data = big_data.copy()
del big_data
```

Comment: Data is big and I'm not ready to deepcopy it. Look I need solution to find a delete all links.

Comment: If I am not mistaken then the `copy` function does a shallow copy. Because of the way dictionaries are implemented in python it doesn't seem like you can force it to free the memory in another way. For more information see https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2010/the-mighty-dictionary-55.html at 26:30. Of course you could also rewrite the implementation to store the big data in separate variables then reference counting should automatically free memory.